# After installing .net 3.5 sp1 I can not create any file in a website?

Tags: asp.net

After installing .net 3.5 sp1 , I cant not create any files from asp.net page it always throws an exception :"access to path is denied" . I set all the permisions of asp.net worker process account to full control but it did not work .

Answer (score 1):

First of all, confirm that it is indeed a user permissions error by temporarily bestowing "Everyone" full permission in that dir. (This of course assumes you're in a test environment!)  If it still doesn't work, something else is going on.

Now then... what about "Network Service?"  What about the user permissions IIS is configured to use for anonymous access?  Often this is "IUSR_[hostname]".

Good information here:
http://www.bluevisionsoftware.com/WebSite/TipsAndTricksDetails.aspx?Name=AspNetAccount